# Sitecore Set the Number of Components

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Is it possible to set the number of components in placeholder?

We can add as many as components in placeholder by using "Add to here" in gray box even the component has been already added.

I'd like to say that

> In plcaceholder named 'bodyArea', you can set only one component in 'bodyArea' placeholder and you will not add any other component additionally.

Is there anyway how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many ways, but this is what I used before.

```cs
// Check the number of renderings in placeholder
public static bool numberOfRenderings(string placeholderName)
{
    bool rendering = true;
    var renderingReferences = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
    int renderingsInPlaceholder = renderingReferences.Where(r => r.Placeholder.EndsWith('/' + placeholderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count();

    if (renderingsInPlaceholder > 1)
    {
        return rendering = false;
    }
    return rendering;
}
```

In View.cshtml

```cs
if (@yourObject.numberOfRenderings("your-placeholder-key")) {
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("your-placeholder-key")
}
else 
{
    @Html.Raw("<div>Only one rendering item is available in this placeholder.</div>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a blog where is describing how to restrict number of allowed controls :

http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2014/restricting-the-number-of-components-in-the-sitecore-page-editor/

Other solution is using rules :

http://dotnetmafia.com/blogs/kevin/archive/2013/07/10/placeholder-settings-rules.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I have already checked those articles, but I was looking for simplest way to solve it. I tried to use this (https://gist.github.com/jasonicarter/a267c7360a6e27487bd7) and add condition, but it is not working..

Comment: Solution is very simple, you need to modify just two files, but If you find simpler solution please add it here, I'm curious about it.

Comment: I'm using MVC and I don't know how to translate `<sc:placeholder runat="server" key="content" Parameter="allowedcontrols=1" />` to MVC.

`@Html.Sitecore.Placeholder("content", new { Parameter="allowedcontrols=1" }` I don't think this works